# How to check if T is a list of objects in a generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am trying to write a generic method for deserializing from json file(s) with Json.NET
I want to be able to support deserializing files that contain objects and also arrays of objects. Below are simplified versions of the two generic methods I have at the moment:

```
/// <summary>   Deserializes object or an array of objects from a list of files. </summary>
public static List<T> Deserialize<T>(List<string> filePathsList)
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var file in filePathsList)
        // HOW DO I FIND OUT IF T IS A LIST HERE?
        // Resharper says: the given expression is never of the provided type
        if (typeof(T) is List<object>)
        {
            var deserialized = Deserialize<List<T>>(file);
            result.AddRange(deserialized);
        }
        // Resharper says: Suspicious type check: there is not type in the solution
        // which is inherited from both 'System.Type' and 'System.Collections.IList'
        else if (typeof(T) is IList)
        {
            // deserializing json file with an array of objects
            var deserialized = Deserialize<List<T>>(file);
            result.AddRange(deserialized);
        }
        else
        {
            // deserializing a single object json file
            var deserialized = Deserialize<T>(file);
            result.Add(deserialized);
        }
    return result;
}


/// <summary>   Deserializes object or an array of objects from a file. </summary>
public static T Deserialize<T>(string filepath)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText(filepath));
}
```

The problem is, I need to **know** if the T is an object or a List of objects, **before** deserializing. How do I check for that inside the generic method? Because resharper gives me warnings and I can't seem to figure this out.

---

Edit: I made a mistake in the example code, as @Medo42 points out, it would call Deserialize() with a `List<List<Something>>`
Also, I should not have included an example involving the json serialization at all, it should have been more generic. The question is about finding out if T is  a list of objects.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you saw my answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but it's too long for a comment and might help you understand some of the issues better.

```
// Resharper says: the given expression is never of the provided type
if (typeof(T) is List<object>)
```

And Resharper is right. The `is` operator checks whether the instance on the left is of the type on the right, so in your case it checks if `typeof(T)` is an instance of `List<object>`. However, `typeof(T)` returns a `Type` instance which *represents* the type of `T`. The correct way to check (if you are after the exact type) would be

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(List<object>))
```

But note that this will only apply if `T` is *exactly* `List<object>`. If it is also OK to have a subtype of `List<object>`, the line would be

```
if (typeof(List<object>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
```

But your problems don't end there. You seem to assume that `List<object>` is a supertype of all lists. This is not the case, even if we can assume that we will only ever work with the `List<T>` implementation for lists. The reson for this is that `List<T>` is *invariant*.

Invariance means that a list of cats is not a list of mammals. If this seems counterintuitive, that's because you think of a list as a fixed collection that you want to read from. However, you can also add new items to a C# list, and if you were allowed to treat a `List<Cat>` as a `List<Mammal>` you could end up trying to add an elephant to that list, and this would cause no end of confusion to anyone else still holding a reference to that list as a `List<Cat>`.

For a solution to the type checking problem, I think drf's comment to dotctor's answer is the cleanest way to do what you think you want to do:

```
typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)
```

As a final aside, the following code also looks wonky:

```
var deserialized = Deserialize<List<T>>(file);
```

You do this after figuring out that `T` is really a `List<Something>`, so you're now trying to deserialize your file as a `List<List<Something>>`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank You. Exactly - I noticed, that I made a mistake in my example in the line **var deserialized = Deserialize<List<T>>(file);** Realized that the example completely does not work, for what I'm after and was about to edit and re-write the question, when all thse answers started popping up. Thanks you for explaining.

Comment: Btw: You can use covariance and contravariance just with interfaces

Answer (score 6):

You can check it easily

```
if (typeof(T).Name == "List`1")
{
    // T is a generic list
}
```

As mentioned by [drf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859891/drf) a better way which does not rely on internal implementations is:

```
if (typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{
    // T is a generic list
}
```

Comment: Or equivalently, `typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)`

Answer (score 2):

You dont need this, you can simplify your code just using LINQ!!!

```
/// <summary>
///     Deserializes object or an array of objects from a list of files.
/// </summary>
public static List<T> Deserialize<T>(List<string> filePathsList)
{
    return filePathsList
        .Select(System.IO.File.ReadAllText)
        .Select(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will actually use this, even though this was only the example code.

Comment: @cryodream Sou should my question be the right one?

Comment: sorry, the question wasn't about json deserializing, but about how to find out if T is a list of objects. Your solution is very useful, only it bypasses the question completely :) It's my bad - I should've made a simpler basic example and more generic question.

Answer (score 1):

@Hamid Pourjam's answer is good, but throw an exception for non-generic types, so you should check `IsGenericType` too. here is helper method for doing that.

```
public bool IsList(object o)
{
    if (o == null) return false;

    var type = o.GetType();
    return o is IList && type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<>));
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

// #1
var foo = new Foo { Key = "value" };

// #2
var foos = new List<Foo>();
foos.Add(foo);

// #3
var lst = new List<object>();
lst.Add(new { Name = "John" });

IsList(foo); // false
IsList(foos); // true
IsList(lst); // true
```